# payload is too large when sending byte with refit

Tags: c#, node.js, image, xamarin.forms, refit

here is the client side error

```
 Refit.ApiException
   Message=Response status code does not indicate success: 413 (Payload Too 
   Large).
   Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
    at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2[T,TBody]. 
   <BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0 (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, 
   System.Threading.CancellationToken ct, System.Object[] paramList) [0x002bd] 
   in <cda9777f03ee4e9188064495e9f2e568>:0 
  at Kula.Addprofilepicture.Postbase (System.Byte[] base64strings) [0x0002b] in 
   C:\Users\blain\Desktop\Kula2\Kulaaa\Kula\Kula\Addprofilepicture.xaml.cs:81 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c. 
  <ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in 
   <19853c43ab794d18ab1a33ecb65b3c4d>:0 
  at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in 
   <8c07a09624c14764b43f6b946a5a1f23>:0 
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in 
  `enter code here` <8c07a09624c14764b43f6b946a5a1f23>:0 
   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr 
   native__this) [0x00009] in <8c07a09624c14764b43f6b946a5a1f23>:0 
   at (wrapper dynamic-method) 
   Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.43(intptr,intptr)
```

server side error

```
 PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at IncomingMessage.onData 
    (C:\Users\blain\Desktop\KulaaBackend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:246:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_common.js:128:22)
```

server side code

```
app.post('/Phototest', (request, response) =>{
  console.log('request tried');
  console.log(request);

})
```

post byte code

```
    public async void Postbase(byte[] base64strings) {

            /*
            base64s s = new base64s()
            {
                base64string = base64strings

            };
            string stringpayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);
            await apiRequestHelper.RequestSaveProfilephotoAsync(stringpayload);
            */
            await myAPI.PostProfilePhoto(base64strings);

        }
```

here is the refit post i also stopped url encoding it because that might make it too large i think. so i am just sending it as a byte and nothing else. in the future i may need to send an email or token with it though.

```
 [Post("/Phototest")]
        Task<string> PostProfilePhoto(Byte[] data);
```

if you know of a better format to send it in that is shorter that would be awesome because i will have to pay for how much data i send to servers in future.

Comment: Try to console.log `request.body` to check if it has any data at all.

Comment: who is saying the request is too long?  Is it a server error or a client error?

Comment: @Jason if i try to send it like above it never makes it to the server. the error comes from visual studio and server side never logs request was even tried. if i try to send it as a byte[] and not a json string it just comes up as undefined with no contents

Comment: @Dijkstra if i log a request which i have done it comes up very log and the part containing the request just says its  undefined. but as a string it never makes it

Comment: @jason am i not supposed to send it as base 64 or byte is their a more efficient option thats shorter?

Comment: a 414 "Request URI is too long" is a **server** error.  Please post the **exact** exception message you are receiving

Comment: @Jason sorry for the slow response but heres the error System.UriFormatException
  Message=Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long. and i will add picture. i could be wrong it might be on the server but ussually it will give me an error on the server or at least do console.log('request tried') and on client side it will say something like internal server error

Comment: I suspect refit is trying to urlencode your data and is barfing because of the size.

Comment: @Jason i am beginner tryna learn so am i trying to send it in a ridiculous format or something. cause i also tried base64 which is also long. this is my first time trying to send an image string rather then smaller strings and ints. any help info or implementations would be awesome.

Comment: There’s no reason you can’t just send a byte[], but it really depends on what your server will accept

Comment: i sent a byte straight and getting this error clientside `Refit.ApiException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 413 (Payload Too Large).'` and this serverside `PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at IncomingMessage.onData (C:\Users\blain\Desktop\KulaaBackend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:246:12)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_common.js:128:22)`

Comment: @Jason i will add new code

Comment: @jason app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'5000mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:'5000mb',extended: true})); solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'5000mb'})); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:'5000mb',extended: true})); solved my problem

Comment: Could you please mark your post as an answer so that others who has similar question could get help from here?

Comment: stack overflow doesnt allow me till later @jessieZhang-MSFT it says i can tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Try it! It work for me. Express v4
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));